# Getting error while trying to zip two list that are not equal in size in python

Tags: python

I have two lists that are different in size

```
 a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
 b=[3,6,7,8]
```

Or

```
 a=[3,4,5,6,7]
 b=[1,2,3,4,16,7,7,8,0]
```

Now i want to zip those two lists , which are not equal in size 
     c=zip(a,b)

so that i can do

```
 for i,j in c:
   print i , j
```

Please suggest .

Comment: ...and what's wrong with `c = zip(a, b)`?

Comment: And what exactly are you going to do after the shorter list runs out?

Comment: You can use itertools `izip_longest`.

Comment: `itertools.zip_longest(a, b)` which will fill the shorter iterable with `None`.  Supply a `fillvalue` if you want something other than `None`.

Comment: If you were going to do something like add the numbers together you might want a `fillvalue` of `0`.  For example `[i + j for (i, j) in itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)]` gives `[4, 6, 8, 10, 23, 7, 7, 8, 0]`.

Comment: thats great man , thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use izip_longest from itertools:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
b=[3,6,7,8]

new_val = list(izip_longest(a, b))
```

This will give:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8), (5, None), (6, None)]
```

izip_longest (or zip_longest in Python3) will replace None with occurrence of a mismatch in lengths between two or more lists being zipped.

Comment: I will check and tell u

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: izip_longest was renamed to zip_longest in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 :

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
b=[3,6,7,8]

new_val = list(zip_longest(a, b))
```